# Upgrade Visual Studio 2005 solutions to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to move my project from Vs2005 to VS 2015.
Could you please let me know what might be the changes in solution file i should be looking for apart from Version description change. ?

Comment: IMO, this is a "too broad" question!

Comment: Sorry as i am a novice in VS,but is it possible to give some clues on what major differences are there in the two Vs solution file formats

Comment: Why do you bother about the differences in file formats? Visual Studio 2015 should be able to open VS 2005 solution, save it newer format.

Comment: @user1 VS2005 is already MSBuild based.

Comment: @AmitSingh you are facing far more issues than simply the file format. That's a 10 years gap and each VS release/Windows releases in between contributes some breaking changes. You will probably have to try out the break-and-fix approach.

Comment: In simple words, VS 2005 based solution is not guaranteed to build under VS 2015 after you upgrade it. And even if it builds, there is no guarantee the program would just work fine. So it isn't only about the file format differences, you will have to fix all breaking changes in code, make them compatible to VS 2015. This is seriously pain in ***

Comment: I tried my hand but i am stuck in porting the property sheets Can anyone share some resource /advice on how to port.The vs2005 project has different tags i think